# How can I make cleaner the reference list with sphinx python?

Tags: html, frontend, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

In the current situation, I have the following structure (list in reference of auto-documentation page):
doc_1.module_1
doc_1.module_2
doc_1.module_3
doc_2.module_1
doc_2.module_2

to be more clear, I inserted a screenshot of the current situation.

I want it to be cleaner, for example:
doc_1 (openable, then I see the list of modules)

- module_1
- module_2
- module_3
  doc_2
- module_1
- module_2

I am trying to do this through modifying the index.rst file but unsuccessly.
I expect to have in my html page of autodocumentation a openable link with inside its modules.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot is missing, so I cannot comment. However, openable, as in tree-style navigation, is possible with some custom Sphinx themes. [Here we are using the Furo theme](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/api/_autosummary_uniswap_v2/eth_defi.uniswap_v2.deployment.html).

[image]

You get a tree style navigation on left.

API documentation is laid out as:

.. code-block:: rest

```
Uniswap v2 API
--------------

.. autosummary::
   :toctree: _autosummary_uniswap_v2
   :recursive:

   eth_defi.uniswap_v2.deployment
   eth_defi.uniswap_v2.pair
   eth_defi.uniswap_v2.fees
   eth_defi.uniswap_v2.analysis
   eth_defi.uniswap_v2.utils
   eth_defi.uniswap_v2.swap
   eth_defi.uniswap_v2.liquidity
   eth_defi.uniswap_v2.oracle
   eth_defi.uniswap_v2.token_tax
```

Some `autosummary` default templates have been modified a bit.

[Full source code is available in the docs folder](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/api/_autosummary_uniswap_v2/eth_defi.uniswap_v2.deployment.html).

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'm trying to replicate the structure of this docs folder, it seems to work, but it cannot load the content, there is only the title of section/paragraph "uniswap_v2"

Comment: It is probably because of Python import errors. You can see any errors when you run Sphinx `make html` locally .Because `autodoc` is a bit difficult to work tool, it splashes a lot of errors with warnings and unneeded messages, so reading the logs carefully is the key.

Comment: Also make sure all related bits are enabled in Sphinx's `conf.py`

Comment: Thank you @Mikko , studying the Git repo of this website, the problem was the **conf.py** file where I had wrong path objects. I solved great part of my issue but still got a  problem which stucks me to conclude my development.
I have a file called lambdas.py which should be generated a related documentation page with sphinx. I tried several ways but sphinx cannot read that as a python script. I don't understand why

Comment: Can you open a new question with relevant information from conf.py and Sphinx build error log?

Comment: Thanks you again @Mikko, I have solved the last problem of my dev, it was about a error of import of custom library which is not installed in the venv so for those packages the content was not showed in the html page.